# How do I make my SumIf Function run through until last range of my data on VBA Code

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-2010

Here is my SumIf Formula

=SUMIF($C$26:$C$43,$C$6,D26:D43)

The C6 is fixed so I lock it so the cell won't run if I drag it

The problem is the range and the sum range

The starting row column of the range (C26) and the sum range (D26) are always the same but not for the last row because my data quantity is not always the same (sometimes it goes until 100 sometimes less)

How can I change the VBA formula of the SumIf to match exactly the same quantity of my data?

here's my SumIf VBA Code (Got it from the record it)

```
"=SUMIF(R26C3:R43C3,R6C3,R[20]C:R[37]C)"
```

Comment: What defines the size of the data range? is the data range 'all non-blank cells in column D' or is it more complex than that?

Comment: Or do you have the data range stored as a variable? if so you could use `rangevariable.Address` when assembling the formula, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.address) for details

Comment: all non-blank cells only in columns C and D only
so column C is not always the same quantity (can be 50 or more or less) and the D column follows the column C. C is the criteria range and D is the sum range

Comment: Then the formula `=SUMIF(C:C, $C$6, D:D)` should achieve the same end?

Comment: @SpencerBarnes would it run through column C and D until the last row of the sheet?

Comment: yes it would - `C:C` refers to the entire column

Comment: @SpencerBarnes well it seems that it will make the file heavier than before. I have tried that before and it very laggy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, try the next way. The code must determine the last cell in C:C and then use it. There are more possibilities to do that. As the following code does, or using directly in the string formula, replacing (existing) 43 (`"=SUMIF($C$26:$C$" & lastR ...`:

```
Sub formulaUntilLast()
  Dim lastR As Long, rngC As Range, RngD As Range, strFormula As String
  lastR = ActiveSheet.Range("C" & rows.count).End(xlUp).row
  Set rngC = Range("C26:C" & lastR)
  Set RngD = Range("D26:D" & lastR)

  strFormula = "=SUMIF(" & rngC.Address & ",$C$6," & rngC.Address & ")"
  Debug.Print strFormula
End Sub
```

Comment: so if I want to add more the sumif formula (C7, so on), I just need to add under the str formula? or should I type the formula then the debug.print?

Comment: @TheLSD Not exactly...:) `strFormula` and `Debug.Print` are only used to visually present the result. In fact you should directly allocate the formula to a range. Something like: `ActiveCell.Formula = "=SUMIF(" & rngC.Address & ",$C$6," & rngC.Address & ")"`. Of course, instead of the active cell, you can use any range.

Comment: Ooh.. I see. Thats why when I try it with more sumif formula (with `strformula`) it stopped then I change to `sheets(1).Range ("D6").Formula`, It work perfectly.
Thank you for the code! It works perfectly!

Comment: @TheLSD If you need to place it on a bigger range, but incrementing "C6", it can be placed on the whole range at once... The code can be easily adapted to work with ranges in another sheet. You should only change `rng.Address(External:=True)...`

Comment: I try to add the formula to sum it with the data from the left side
`Sheets(1).Range("e6").Formula = "=SUMIF(" & rngC.Address & ",$C$6," & rngC.Address & ") + RC [-1]"`
I add up RC [-1] as the indicator for the column before but it comes with error
do you have recommendation of what should I use to change the RC [-1]?

Comment: @TheLSD You cannot mix `Formula` with `FormulaR1C1`... Please, directly write the cell address you need to add (`+ B6`, for instance).

Comment: I have about 12 column, so I need to write the code one by one? like + B6 then after that change the range, insert the formula + the cell before? can I use like dynamic range?

Comment: @TheLSD  I am afraid, I cannot understand what you mean... Please, try a reproductible example. If, for instance you need to use the formula on the range `A6:G6` you can write the formula at once to the whole range. And use `+ A6`. Excel will automatically increment the column. The same for row, if the case (the range involves more than one row)...

Comment: sorry for my bad explaination. So as you said before that I need to add the range specifically and 1 by 1 `+ D6` for example on E6. After that, I want to add the same formula on F6, I need to give `sumif formula + E6` until column O.
Can I make the `+ D6`,`+ E6`, so on as dynamic so I can use autofill to fill until column O? or there's no way to do that except to write it down one by one?

Comment: @TheLSD I missed this comment... You should simple use: `Range("E6:O6").Formula = strFormula`. The necessary incrementation, in terms of columns, will be done for all the range...

Comment: So I write the code `Sheets(1).Range("e6").Formula = "=SUMIF(" & rngC.Address & ",$C$6," & rngC.Address & ") + D6` first. After that, I add next line as what you suggest right?